# Google Sheets Problem with Chart Axis

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts, time-series

I have a Google Sheet with a some data that I need to chart. The horizontal axis should be a list of dates. When I plot the chart, though, it's inserting dates that aren't part of the data set. For example:

[image: data table]

[image: chart]

I've been playing with this for a while, and I can't figure out how to get it to use my actual headers as the axis rather than inserting dates that aren't there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row you are using for labels contains dates, the spreadsheet supposes that you need an accurate representation of time. So it arranges the data chronologically and marks the time axis at equal time intervals:

[image]

If you want the specific dates to be used as labels, this means they should be used like text labels. Select the top row and apply `Format->Number->Plain Text`:

[image]

Now the columns are labeled with the text from the top row, and they are presented in the order of appearance in the spreadsheet.